# Extend HTTP Get Url on click (Ionic 2 + Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have recently made a search for my app built in ionic which is pulling from an api using a http get method as below

```
static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
}

searchRecipes(id) {
    var url = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=/////&_app_key=//////&q=' + encodeURI(id);
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
}
```

So far I have the `id` which is what they user types in. I now want to add **filters** to my search (ingredients, cuisine and allergies), this is done by extending the url further with specific calls such as `&allowedAllergy[]` and `allowedDiet[]`.

I currently have a list of items implemented such as, each would have a value set to them, and on click on one it will add to the url provided. Implementation to be the same as http://www.yummly.uk/

```
      <div class="diets">
        <ul>
          <li>Lacto vegetarian</li>
          <li>Ovo vegetarian</li>
          <li>PaleoPescetarian</li>
          <li>Vegan</li>
          <li>Vegetarian</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="allergies">
      <ul>
        <li>Dairy-Free</li>
        <li>Egg-Free</li>
        <li>Gluten-Free</li>
        <li>Peanut-Free</li>
        <li>Seafood-Free</li>
        <li>Sesame-Free</li>
        <li>Soy-Free</li>
        <li>Sulfite-Free</li>
        <li>Tree Nut-Free</li>
        <li>Wheat-Free</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Search Method

recipes: any;

```
searchRecipeDB(event, key) {
    if(event.target.value.length > 2) {
        this.apiAuthentication.searchRecipes(event.target.value).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.recipes = data.matches; 
                console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            },
            () => console.log('Recipe Search Complete')
        );
    }
}
```

If anyone can give advice on how to implement this it would be a life saver! Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here it is component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core"
import {Http} from "@angular/http"

@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit
{
    diets: Array<string> = ['Lacto vegetarian', 'Ovo vegetarian', 'PaleoPescetarian', 'Vegan', 'Vegetarian'];
    allergies: Array<string> = ['Dairy-Free',
                                'Egg-Free',
                                'Gluten-Free',
                                'Peanut-Free',
                                'Seafood-Free',
                                'Sesame-Free',
                                'Soy-Free',
                                'Sulfite-Free',
                                'Tree Nut-Free',
                                'Wheat-Free'];


    id: number = 1;
    selectedDiets: Array<boolean>;
    selectedAllergies: Array<boolean>;
    allowedAllergy: Array<string>;
    allowedCuisine: Array<string>;
    url: string;

    constructor(private http: Http)
    {
        this.selectedDiets = new Array(this.diets.length).fill(false);
        this.selectedAllergies = new Array(this.allergies.length).fill(false);
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
    }

    submit()
    {
        this.processAllergy();
        this.processDiets();
        this.searchRecipes(this.id, this.allowedAllergy, this.allowedCuisine);
    }

    processAllergy()
    {

        this.allowedAllergy = this.selectedAllergies.reduce((selectedList: Array<string>, isSelected: boolean, index: number) =>
        {
            return isSelected ? [...selectedList, this.allergies[index]] : selectedList;
        }, [])

    }

    processDiets()
    {
        this.allowedCuisine = this.selectedDiets.reduce((selectedList: Array<string>, isSelected: boolean, index: number) =>
        {
            return isSelected ? [...selectedList, this.diets[index]] : selectedList;
        }, [])

    }

    searchRecipes(id: number,
                  allowedAllergy: Array<string>,
                  allowedCuisine: Array<string>)
    {


        this.url = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=/////&_app_key=//////&q=' + encodeURI(id.toString());


        if (allowedAllergy.length)
        {
            this.url = this.url + `&allowedAllergy=${encodeURI(allowedAllergy.toString())}`
        }
        if (allowedCuisine.length)
        {
            this.url = this.url + `&allowedCuisine=${encodeURI(allowedCuisine.toString())}`
        }


        console.log(this.url);
        //return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<pre>selectedDiets: {{selectedDiets | json}}</pre>
<pre>selectedAllergies: {{selectedAllergies | json}}</pre>
<pre>allowedAllergy: {{allowedAllergy | json}}</pre>
<pre>selectedAllergies: {{allowedCuisine | json}}</pre>
<div class="diets">
  <strong>Select diet regiments</strong>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let diet of diets; let i = index">
      {{diet}}
      <input type="checkbox"
             [(ngModel)]="selectedDiets[i]">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="allergies">
  <strong>Select allergy requirements</strong>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let allergy of allergies; let i = index">
      {{allergy}}
      <input type="checkbox"
             [(ngModel)]="selectedAllergies[i]">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<pre>{{url}}</pre>
<button (click)="submit()">
  search
</button>
```

Comment: Also if you have any question how it works ask me tomorrow.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this! The way it works is great and I do for the most part get what is going on. However (you're gunna hate me) I now have my search and filtered search working separately as this can see my **Search Method** code in the question. I have tried to change it from `this.apiAuthentication.searchRecipes` to `this.searchRecipes` but it throws up an error stating **Supplied parameters do not match any signature call of target**. Essentially the id instead of being a number, will need to be the value wrote by the user in the search.

Answer (score 0):

try this it a bit basic but will do the job:

```
searchRecipes(id: number,
              allowedAllergy: Array<string>,
              allowedCuisine: Array<string>)
{
    let url = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=/////&_app_key=//////&q=' + encodeURI(id.toString());

    if (allowedAllergy.length)
    {
        url = url + `&allowedAllergy=${allowedAllergy.toString()}`
    }
    if (allowedCuisine.length)
    {
        url = url + `&allowedCuisine=${allowedCuisine.toString()}`
    }

    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I have edited my question to see if it makes a bit more sense now what I'm aiming for

Comment: Stack overflow is not really a code writing service but I am bored at work so will write something up for you. Give me 10 mins.